# Stretching my excel charts even when not targeting the sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I dont understand why it's happening. I'm using a code that checks another sheet, yet my sheet("visualisation") is being affected. Why is that? It's squeezing all my charts...

here is the line :

`lastrow1 = Sheets("SharePoint").Cells(Sheets("SharePoint").Rows.Count, Cells(1, 1).Column).End(xlUp).Row`

This is the entire code:

```
Sub Start()
    Dim name        As String
    Dim name1       As String
    Dim numb        As String
    Dim name3       As String
    Dim lastrow1    As Long
    Dim lastrow2    As Long
    Dim lastrow3    As Long
    Dim x           As String
    
    Columns(7).EntireColumn.Delete
    Columns(8).EntireColumn.Delete
    
    t = 167
    
    lastrow1 = Sheets("SharePoint").Cells(Sheets("SharePoint").Rows.Count, Cells(1, 1).Column).End(xlUp).Row        'Determining the last row of a worksheet 1
    
    lastrow2 = Sheets("GIC").Cells(Sheets("GIC").Rows.Count, Cells(1, 1).Column).End(xlUp).Row        'Determining the last row of a worksheet 2
    
    lastrow3 = Sheets("VALUE").Cells(Sheets("VALUE").Rows.Count, Cells(1, 1).Column).End(xlUp).Row        'Determining the last row of a worksheet 3
    
    For i = 2 To lastrow1
        
        name = Sheets("SharePoint").Range("A" & i & ":" & "A" & i).Value
        name3 = Sheets("SharePoint").Range("C" & i & ":" & "C" & i).Value
        numb = Sheets("SharePoint").Range("B" & i & ":" & "B" & i).Value
        
        For m = 1 To lastrow3
            
            If name = Sheets("VALUE").Cells(m, 1).Value Then
                name1 = Sheets("VALUE").Cells(m, 2).Value
                Exit For
            End If
            
        Next
        
        For q = 2 To lastrow2
            
            If name1 = Sheets("GIC").Range("A" & q & ":" & "A" & q).Value Then
                
                If numb = Sheets("GIC").Range("B" & q & ":" & "B" & q).Value Then
                    
                    ind = 0
                    Exit For
                End If
                
                ind = 1
            Else
                
                ind = 1
                
            End If
        Next
        
        If ind = 1 Then
            Sheets("visualisation").Cells(t, 7).Value = name
            Sheets("visualisation").Cells(t, 8).Value = numb
            Sheets("visualisation").Cells(t, 9).Value = name3
            Sheets("visualisation").Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
            t = t + 1
            ind = 0
        End If
        
    Next
    
End Sub
```

"Visualisation" is the sheet where the charts are being squeezed.

Comment: There should be no connection between the code you posted and your charts getting "squeezed" so it seems there's some other thing you might not be sharing. FYI `Cells(1, 1).Column` is just `1` so you could just use that instead.

Comment: @TimWilliams I updated my post, can you please take a look at it?

Comment: What sheet is `Columns(7).EntireColumn.Delete` (and `Columns(8).EntireColumn.Delete`) run against? Also `Sheets("visualisation").Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit` - this may "squeeze" charts unless you have them set to "Don't move or size with cells"

Comment: @BigBen I should delete those. When I run the debugger, I can see that the sheet start squeezing at the `lastrow1 = Sheets("SharePoint").Cells(Sheets("SharePoint").Rows.Count, Cells(1, 1).Column).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: Make sure your ChartObject properties don't have "Move and Size with Cells" option selected.

Comment: Where can I select "don't move or size with cells"?

Comment: I deleted "autofit" and it worked. thank you@BigBen

Comment: Right-click the chart then "format chart area"